# can you explain the working of ret variable in the code below?

Tags: c++

```
inline int inp() {
    char c = gc();
    while(c<'0' || c>'9') c = gc();
    int ret = 0;
    while(c>='0' && c<='9') {
        ret = (ret << 3) + (ret << 1) + c - 48;
        c = gc();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

What is `ret` trying to do by left shift operators and then subtraction by 48?

Comment: Magic number 48 is the ascii number for `'0'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is some kind of obfuscation or micro-optimization:

- `ret << 3` is `ret * 8`
- `ret << 1` is `ret * 2`

So `(ret << 3) + (ret << 1)` is actually `ret * 10`. Then, on common implementation, the integer value of the character `'0'` is `48` (ascii value), so:

```
(ret << 3) + (ret << 1) - 48
```

Is actually:

```
ret * 10 - '0'
```

So this code is basically a "weird" way of converting a string representing a number (returned by successive call to `gc()`) to an `int`.

Comment: hey thanks for answering!